# mongodb collection fetch information with criteria

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongodb-query

I'm facing the following issue:

I have this data in a collection in mongoDB

```
   { Node: '2', Type: 'temperature', Value: '25.9', _id: 5936f90c81c543363d42f598 },
   { Node: '3', Type: 'temperature', Value: '31.0', _id: 5936f90c81c543363d42f599 },
   { Node: '1', Type: 'humidity', Value: '45.2', _id: 5936f90c81c543363d42f59a },
   { Node: '2', Type: 'humidity', Value: '55.3', _id: 5936f90c81c543363d42f59b }
```

I want to fetch it by type.

Can't find what I'm doing wrong in my code...

```
var MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient
  , assert = require('assert');
var url = 'mongodb://localhost:27017/myproject';
MongoClient.connect(url, function(err, db) {
  assert.equal(null, err);
  if (err) throw err;
  var collection = db.collection('readings');
  collection.find({}).toArray(function(err, result) {
    if (err) throw err;
    //console.log(result); //mostrar os resultados
    var numTemps = 0;
    result.forEach(function(err,doc){
      if ("temperature" in result) {
        numTemps = numTemps + 1;
      };
    });
    var numHums = 0;
    result.forEach(function(err,doc){
      if ("humidity" in result) {
        numHums = numHums + 1;
      };
    });
    console.log("Temps: " + numTemps);
    console.log("Hums: " + numHums);
    db.close();
  });
});
```

Comment: Result in terminal:
    Temps: 0
    Hums: 0

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Thank you all.

Managed to solve this with the following:

```
collection.find({}).toArray(function(err, result) {
if (err) throw err;
//console.log(result);
var numHums = 0;
var numTemps = 0;
var i = 0;
result.forEach(function(err,values){
  console.log(result[i].Type);
  if (result[i].Type == 'humidity') {
    numHums = numHums + 1;
  }
  if (result[i].Type == 'temperature') {
    numTemps = numTemps + 1;
  };
  i = i + 1;
});
console.log("Temps: " + numTemps);
console.log("Hums: " + numHums);
db.close();
});
```

edit:

changed the foreach according to the suggestion of the users here:

```
result.forEach(function(values){ 
 console.log(values.Type); 
 if (values.Type == 'humidity') { 
  numHums = numHums + 1; 
 } 
 if (values.Type == 'temperature') { 
  numTemps = numTemps + 1; 
 }; 
});
```

Comment: You're using `forEach` wrong. See nadavvadan's answer.

Comment: Yep, this is a weird hybrid between `for` and `forEach`. I wouldn't do this

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what is going on there but it looks all wrong.  To get counts for the various types try this:

```
db.readings.count({temperature: $exists: true}})
db.readings.count({humidity: $exists: true}})
```

Answer (score 1):

You have a few bugs.

```
result.forEach(function(err,doc){
      if ("temperature" in result) {
        numTemps = numTemps + 1;
      };
    });
    var numHums = 0;
    result.forEach(function(err,doc){
      if ("humidity" in result) {
        numHums = numHums + 1;
      };
    });
```

I believe what you actually meant was:

```
result.forEach(function(doc){
      if ("temperature" in doc) {
        numTemps = numTemps + 1;
      };
    });
    var numHums = 0;
    result.forEach(function(doc){
      if ("humidity" in doc) {
        numHums = numHums + 1;
      };
    });
```

or, with better formatting and performance (and more [DRY](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself)):

```
result.forEach(function(doc){

  if ("temperature" in doc) {
    numTemps++;
  };

  if ("humidity" in doc) {
    numHums++;
  };

});
```

Comment: What am I missing?  Why would you use this method instead of just calling count?

Comment: Calling count twice is a bit heavier on the Database; I'd probably use 2 count queries as well if the Database isn't that large, or, better yet, use mapReduce (might be an overkill though).

Comment: If the database is large then you are pulling every record and iterating through it.  Count is meant to count records and if you have proper indexing it won't be heavy on the database at all.  I think it's wrong to help him down this road which it seems like it's clearly a bad practice.

Comment: I agree with you and I actually use double `.count`s in production code; However, I wanted to help OP understand what was wrong with their code.

Comment: @AbeMiessler You wouldn't, but this question is pretty bad and likely an X-Y problem, but without the OP providing more info it's hard to say.